# How to uninstall silent a MSI package?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a .msi setup program, built with the [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/).

After installing this package, I can use the Windows Explorer to uninstall it, by a right click to the .msi file, choosing "uninstall":

[image]

After selecting this menu entry, I get a question, if I really want to uninstall this package:

[image]

This question dialog will not show, if I use the settings "add or remove feature" of Windows.

Is there a chance to hide this question dialog from inside the .msi file?

(For explaination: I'm using a `custom action` of the .msi file to ask the user, if he really wants to remove this product. Inside my dialog, I offer a check box to remove all settings complete from the harddisk.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What you are seeing is standard Windows Installer behavior.